# Troubleshooting Large Macro for Word 2016

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to create a **macro for Word 2016** that will automatically edit a document based on a list of about 250 search terms that I used the "find and replace" function to change. When I record the macro from start to finish and attempt to run, I receive a message saying **"Procedure is too long"**. I have looked through answers on here and understand that you can clean up some code and/or create sub sections within the code to troubleshoot. However, I am not sure what I am doing and the code is very long.

Could someone help me please?

portion of code is included below:

[Portion of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgG8y.png)

Comment: A portion of the code is attached below:

Comment: Please include the code, not a picture of the code. Pictures are often difficult to read and the code can't be copied/pasted for testing. Please take a moment to read guidelines on posting questions in the [help].

Comment: Code does not belong in an image. See [this Meta answer](v) for a list of reasons why. Also, as stated now your post is far too vague. If you record the macro and get an error that it's too long, break it into separate actions and record macros for each section, and then you can write one subroutine that executes those macros in order.

Comment: @KenWhite I've seen people say that you can do this and I have tried but it didn't work. What are the appropriate beginning and end codes that start end complete a action (and where do you put them?). I think what I tried had me putting Proc1(), Proc2(), ect after the common code at the beginning and then subproc1(), subproc2(), ect. after, each closed with an end sub.

Comment: You break the task up when recording the macro, not in the macro itself. For instance, if the task is selecting three paragraphs, copying them to a new document, and changing some formatting, you record three macros (one for the selection, one for the copy, one for the formatting), and then create a new sub that calls the selection macro and then the copy macro and then the formatting macro. You then only execute that new sub. I can't tell you exactly how you should break up your task, because I don't know the specifics of your task. You should be able to determine  how to break it into units.

Comment: @KenWhite Where are you creating the new sub? is that what you are coding into a new macro? What code do you use to recall the functions (selection and formatting for instance) inside the new sub? Do you just copy and past the code from the selection and formatting macros? The function I am trying to automate with the macro is the find and replace function with about 250 terms I want it to find and replace. When I record all 250 find and replace at once the macro is too big. I can create 5 different macros to split them up. But how do I compile them into one function?

Comment: You write the new sub in the VB editor. It sounds like you need to find a tutorial or book to learn the basics of VBA (beyond recording macros). Recording macros can only take you so far, as you've already discovered.

Comment: @KenWhite do you have any suggested resources that will help me get a handle on this?

Comment: See the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 0):

Break your macro into steps. The easiest way is (use a **copy** of your document for testing, so you can always put the original text back if you make a mistake!):

- Record a short macro. It doesn't matter what it does. Name it something like `DoAllReplacements`.
- Record a macro that does your first block of replacements. Name it something like `DoReplacement1`.
- View the macros, and edit the `DoReplacement1` macro. Copy all of the text from the end of the comment block to the line just before `End Sub`.
- Put the edit caret (cursor) at the end of the DoReplacement1 `End Sub` and hit enter twice. Enter the following text:

  ```
  Sub DoReplacement2()

  End Sub
  ```
- Paste the code from the clipboard between the `Sub` and `End Sub` lines you just added. Edit the macro code to do your next block of replacements.
- Repeat the above until you have all of your replacements coded, using as many new `DoReplacementX` routines as needed.
- Go back to the very first macro you recorded (`DoAllReplacements`), and remove all of the code between the `Sub DoAllReplacements()` and `End Sub`. Add new calls to the individual `DoReplacementX` macros you wrote.

  ```
  Sub DoAllReplacements()
      DoReplacement1
      DoReplacement2
      DoReplacement3
      ' Etc. until you've added them all
  End Sub
  ```

Exit the macros code window. Use `View Macros`, select your `DoAllReplacements` macro and execute it.